# Texas Holdem - Simulate a round of betting algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, poker

Im trying to create an algorithm for texas holdem simulations, this specific part of the code needs to go around the table taking the decisions from each seated poker bot and betting. The algorithm conconcludes when all of the agents have either folded or gone allIn, or when the highest bet has been called by each remaining player.

This algorithm seems to work 99% of the time, but sometimes there is a corner case where one agent goes allIn and it gets all the way around the table but doesnt make the last agent in the betting order call the AllIn raise.

Can anyone spot a logical error in my code anywhere, or possibly suggest an entirely different algorithm for doing this? Ive tryed catching the error with breakpoints but the problem is that it happens so infrequently its hard to breakpoint the code when this is actually happening.

```
        while (callCount < agentsInHand)
    {


        if (!agents[betPosition].folded && !agents[betPosition].allIn)
        {
            bettingDecision = agents[betPosition].MakeDecision(tournament, this, minRaise, agentsInHand);


            if (bettingDecision[0] == 0 && chipsToCall > 0)
            {
                //fold                    
                agentsInHand--;
                agents[betPosition].folded = true;
                tournament.AddDecision(agents[betPosition], 0d);
            }
            else if (bettingDecision[0] == 1 || ((chipsToCall <= preFlopBets[betPosition] && betRound == 0) ||(chipsToCall <= flopBets[betPosition] && betRound == 1) ||(chipsToCall <= turnBets[betPosition] && betRound == 2) ||(chipsToCall <= riverBets[betPosition] && betRound == 3)) && bettingDecision[0] == 0)
            {
                //call                    
                tournament.AddDecision(agents[betPosition], 1d);

                if (betRound == 0)
                {
                    int chipsBet = agents[betPosition].BetChips(chipsToCall - preFlopBets[betPosition], this);
                    pot += chipsBet;
                }
                else if (betRound == 1)
                {
                    int chipsBet = agents[betPosition].BetChips(chipsToCall - flopBets[betPosition], this);
                    pot += chipsBet;
                }
                else if (betRound == 2)
                {
                    int chipsBet = agents[betPosition].BetChips(chipsToCall - turnBets[betPosition], this);
                    pot += chipsBet;
                }
                else
                {
                    int chipsBet = agents[betPosition].BetChips(chipsToCall - riverBets[betPosition], this);
                    pot += chipsBet;
                }

                if (agents[betPosition].allIn)
                {
                    agentsInHand--;
                }
                else
                {
                    callCount++;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                //raise
                callCount = 1;

                if (betRound == 0)
                {
                    int chipsBet = agents[betPosition].BetChips(bettingDecision[1], this);
                    tournament.AddDecision(agents[betPosition], Convert.ToDouble(preFlopBets[betPosition]) / Convert.ToDouble(chipsToCall));
                    pot += chipsBet;
                    if (minRaise < preFlopBets[betPosition] - chipsToCall)
                    {
                        minRaise = preFlopBets[betPosition] - chipsToCall;
                    }
                    chipsToCall = preFlopBets.Max();
                }
                else if (betRound == 1)
                {
                    int chipsBet = agents[betPosition].BetChips(bettingDecision[1], this);
                    tournament.AddDecision(agents[betPosition], Convert.ToDouble(flopBets[betPosition]) / Convert.ToDouble(chipsToCall));
                    pot += chipsBet;
                    if (minRaise < flopBets[betPosition] - chipsToCall)
                    {
                        minRaise = flopBets[betPosition] - chipsToCall;
                    }
                    chipsToCall = flopBets.Max();
                }
                else if (betRound == 2)
                {
                    int chipsBet = agents[betPosition].BetChips(bettingDecision[1], this);
                    tournament.AddDecision(agents[betPosition], Convert.ToDouble(turnBets[betPosition]) / Convert.ToDouble(chipsToCall));
                    pot += chipsBet;
                    if (minRaise < turnBets[betPosition] - chipsToCall)
                    {
                        minRaise = turnBets[betPosition] - chipsToCall;
                    }
                    chipsToCall = turnBets.Max();
                }
                else
                {
                    int chipsBet = agents[betPosition].BetChips(bettingDecision[1], this);
                    tournament.AddDecision(agents[betPosition], Convert.ToDouble(riverBets[betPosition]) / Convert.ToDouble(chipsToCall));
                    pot += chipsBet;
                    if (minRaise < riverBets[betPosition] - chipsToCall)
                    {
                        minRaise = riverBets[betPosition] - chipsToCall;
                    }
                    chipsToCall = riverBets.Max();
                }

                if (agents[betPosition].allIn)
                {
                    agentsInHand--;

                    if (betRound == 0)
                    {
                        if (preFlopBets[betPosition] >= chipsToCall)
                        {
                            callCount = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (betRound == 1)
                    {
                        if (flopBets[betPosition] >= chipsToCall)
                        {
                            callCount = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (betRound == 2)
                    {
                        if (turnBets[betPosition] >= chipsToCall)
                        {
                            callCount = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (riverBets[betPosition] >= chipsToCall)
                        {
                            callCount = 0;
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }

        betPosition++;
        if (betPosition == 9)
        {
            betPosition = 0;
        }
        while (!IsSeatTaken(betPosition))
        {
            betPosition++;
            if (betPosition == 9)
            {
                betPosition = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're bluffing. That code works.

Comment: Im confused why I got a -1 for this question? Some feedback would be helpful

Comment: @user1296932 - I bet its because this belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) , people are very picky here.

Comment: I would sprinkle the code with logging to file. Delete the contents at the start of each round, break all when the problem occurs, and then search the file for clues.

Comment: @user, `can anyone spot a logical error in my code anywhere, or possibly suggest an entirely different algorithm for doing this?` is far too broad for Stack Overflow. Your code snippet is 160-something lines long, are you actually expecting us to debug that code for you?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I was expecting people who dont have the time to ignore this, but I guess that doesnt happen lol.

Comment: Actually, instead of logging to file you can use [tracepoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on every relevant line of code, writing all relevant bits of data, and later analyze the contents of the output window.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi also this seems like the type of algorithm that people have created before multiple times so i figured a reference would be readily available to the right person.

Comment: The -1 could be because people don't like questions involving finding bugs with code. You also didn't describe the exact steps to reproduce very well (which should preferably just be "run the program"), or exactly what happens, or post an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). @RadioSpace I don't believe a question about bug belongs on Code Review - it's only for working code.